# How to output DB table update count report without accessing Db2 BSDS in BMC Log Master

Tags: db2-zos

All.
I am thinking of using BMC Log Master for Db2 to report the number of Db2 DB table updates.
At this time,is it possible to specify the Db2 archive log dataset and output a report without accessing BSDS ?

Comment: I am thinking of specifing the following for SYSIN.
INPUT DB2LOG (Db2 archive log dataset name)